# Can Docker automatically add IP addresses to the host upon running container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, docker

I've got a server on hetzner.de with around 16 public IPv4 addresses.

Right now I'm running containers like this:

```
sudo docker run -d --name test6 -it -p 5.1.2.3:80:80 sunebeck/apache-php
```

This will initially yield this error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 5.1.2.3:80: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

Which is fixed by adding the ip address on the host manually:

```
ip addr add 5.1.2.3 dev eth0
```

After which it works as intended and the service is exposed as port 80 on 5.1.2.3. However it's a bit cumbersome to manually manage this.

Can Docker automatically add/remove IP addresses from the host as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Docker itself can't do that.  With a few exceptions (such as the iptables rules that Docker creates when starting a container), a container can't modify the network environment of the host.

The easiest way to solve this problem is probably just arrange to assign all your addresses to interfaces when the host starts up, using e.g., `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>` on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL, or `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian/Ubuntu.

This way, the addresses will be available on the interfaces before Docker starts running, and your port binding will work without a problem.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but I also wouldn't want a physical server to claim an IP address if another host might be the one using it at a given moment.

Comment: But I can of course solve it by making a wrapper script. Or maybe use some of the existing services for 'orchestrating' larger installs.

Comment: Right; I was going to suggest that using an orchestration layer like Kubernetes might help manage this better.  I once wrote a tool (called [kiwi](https://github.com/larsks/kiwi)) that did exactly what you want, but it was never terribly robust and does not work with modern versions of Kubernetes.

Comment: Nice. Think I'll have a more in-depth look at Kubernetes!